# Require selection - Excel VBA List Box

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have an Excel UserForm, which submits data to a worksheet. I have built in data validation that requires each text box to have a value entered, e.g.:

```
Private Sub Button_Submit_Click()
'Data Validation
If Me.txtCVS.Value = "" Then
Me.txtCVS.SetFocus
MsgBox "'CVs Screened' is a mandatory field. Enter daily figure or zero.", vbOKOnly, "Required     Field"
Exit Function
```

However, I don't know what code to use to require a selection from a list box - users select their name from the list box before entering in their daily figures. Some users, it seems, can't remember to click their name(!!!).

Does anybody have a piece of workable code I can use to require a selection before submitting results? It doesn't seem to work in the same way as the text box text above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below function which iterates through all the items in the listbox and returns true/false if anything is selected or not.

```
Private Sub Button_Submit_Click()

    If Not IsAnythingSelected(ListBox1) Then
        MsgBox "Please select your name"
    End If

End Sub

Function IsAnythingSelected(lBox As Control) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    Dim selected As Boolean
    selected = False
    For i = 1 To lBox.ListCount
        If lBox.selected(i) Then
            selected = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    IsAnythingSelected = selected
End Function
```

Comment: I seem to be having a little trouble with this one. I copied the above code to sit below my Button_Submit_Click() subroutine, and above my text box data validation (above). However, I get a compile error because the text box validation is after the End Function, but within the End Sub. I think my problem is having a function and a sub mixed in together. Is there any way to combine both the above loop function and the text box validation in my original post?

Comment: @cazzzac no, just add the `If Not` til `end if` part to your current Button_Submit_Click() and add the whole `Function` part below any subs

Comment: THANK YOU!!!
That was entirely logical, but in my brain-dead state I couldn't work it out. Works beautifully.

Comment: Hmmm, so the data validation works fine, and the rest of the form submits to the dataset no problems. But the form won't transfer the value selected from the name list box. It transfers whatever was pre-selected in the VBA Project. E.g. if the pre-selected value was empty and I select a name, the empty value is transferred; if the pre-selected value is 'Alex' and i select 'Hannah', it will transfer 'Alex'.

Comment: Is it possible that the above data validation may have cleared my selection to the pre-selected value?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
For i = 1 to lBox.ListCount
```

to the following:

```
For i = 0 To lBox.ListCount - 1
```